# Django with VS2010 gives me "ImportError: No module named django.core.management" when running

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/django-with-visual-studio/) and I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I'm completely new to python.  I believe Visual studio is using a version of python I already had installed in `c:\Python27`, could that be causing a problem?

[image]

Someone mentioned in a link I found that they had to copy the 'django' folder to the project folder, but I don't know where that would be.  I don't even know what the error means really unless there's a missing package (like dll or assembly in .NET?), but I don't know what paths python would use to try to find a package or even what one would look like.

I see there's a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable that I don't have declared, should I declare that?  Should it point to the C:\Python27 directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with a lot of fooling around I found this directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\PythonDetectInstalls
```

In a mangled sub-folder there is a powershell script `DetectPythonInistalls.ps1` that has these two lines for checking if python is installed already:

```
$regKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
$correctRegKey = "hklm:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\$pythonVersion\InstallPath";
```

Uninstalling all my pythons did not remove these keys.  After removing these registry keys with `regedit`, WPI allowed me to install its own version of python 2.7 and all the other goodies to go with the [Windows Azure Python SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

First, do you have checked your "Python Environment" in your project folder? It may seems like...

[image: Python Environment]

Here you may find your django with version. If you dont find it then compile setup.py from django folder again with desire python version. And then right click on "Python Environments" from your project and click on "Add/Remove Python Environments" to select python version.